# CloudFormation - obtaining template from a repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-cloudformation, devops, pipeline

Can someone list for me the steps needed in order to obtain a template from Azure DevOps repo and have AWS Cloud Formation use it to build a stack.

Interested in best practices and some high-level steps please / requirements E.G. do I need AWS Pipelines? AWS Azure Toolkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the cleaner ways that I could think of doing this is integrating your DevOps repository with an S3 bucket and then triggering AWS CodePipeline to deploy the stack from the S3 bucket.

The flow would be something like,

1. Create a bucket in S3 to hold the cf template
2. [Create](https://skundunotes.com/2020/09/13/deploy-from-azure-devops-to-aws-s3-in-3-steps/) a service connection request in DevOps repo, this should push the template to S3 every time changes are deployed
3. [Create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html) an AWS CodePipeline workflow that takes the template as input from S3 and deploys it to CloudFormation

Comment: I see, thanks. There is a requirement to Azure DevOps though as the repo. I should have mentioned this clearer, sorry...

Comment: @coconutoilguy You're welcome. Just to be clear, with this approach you will still be pushing your template to the Azure DevOps repo, its just that it will push those changes to S3 from the backend via service connection request.